# scrolling up set of pictures up and down on hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a portfolio for a small firm that I have. I was planning to have the same function as this one from e-onetime http://eone-time.com/#team do you think this is possible with a gif image. The function that I would like to have is that on hover gif animated 1 time, or should I set multiple images like what they did on their portfolio and let it scroll up and down onclick.

This is a section from my TEAM section in which the static gif and animated gif is located:

```
<!-- Team Section -->
<section id="team" class="content-section text-center">
    <div class="team-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h1>TEAM</h1>
                <HR>

            </div>
        </div>
<!-- Team Grid  --><section class="main">
    <div id="items">
        <div class="item">
            <a id="1" class="work page-scroll">
                <img class="media" src="img/tryimages/greggy.png"/>
                <div class="content">
                <img class="media" src="img/tryimages/greggy.gif"/>
                <!--<h2 class="title">Click</h2>!-->
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a id="2" class="work page-scroll">
                <img class="media" src="img/tryimages/dennise.png"/>
                <div class="content">
                <img class="media" src="img/tryimages/dennise.gif"/>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a id="3" class="work page-scroll">
                <img class="media" src="img/tryimages/jm.png"/>
                <div class="content">
                <img class="media" src="img/tryimages/jm.gif"/>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a id="4" class="work page-scroll">
                <img class="media" src="img/tryimages/hannah.png"/>
                <div class="content">
                <img class="media" src="img/tryimages/hannah.gif"/>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!-- End of Works Grid  -->
```

This is the javascript function I have for my team profiler:

```
</script>
<!--Team JS Function!-->
<script>
$("#items a").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#pages div, #pages2 div").siblings().hide("slow");
  $("#pages div#" + id + "").toggle("slow");
});
$("#items2 a").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#pages2 div, #pages div").siblings().hide("slow");
  $("#pages2 div#" + id + "").toggle("slow");
});
</script>
```

Comment: could you provide us with some code of what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

just animate `background-image` using css keyframes for a `.animated` class, and then add this to your javascript:

```
$('#items a').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('animated');
});
```

Comment: Thanks will work on this and let you know the result. :)